# event.target.id from click event called from div contents rather than from assigned div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a click event for a bunch of dynamically generated `div`s. However, sometimes when I click on the `div`, **the click function  is invoked with an `event.target` that is not the div the click function was assigned to.** This is happening when I click on the `div` close to its text rather than in empty space within the `div`. How can I stop this?

Here's the code I'm using to set up the `div`s:

```
for (i = 1; i <= pageArray.length; i++) {

    var divName = "div_" + i
    console.log("adding divname with id " + divName);
    console.log("<div id = '" + divName + "' class = 'unselected' style = 'overflow:hidden; background-color: yellow; float:left;'></div>");
    $('#toAppend').append("<div id = '" + divName + "' class = 'unselected' style = 'overflow:hidden; background-color: yellow; float:left;'></div>");
    $("#" + divName);
    .load(pageArray[i - 1]);
    .css("width", Math.round(widthPer * portionDiv));
    .css("height", heightPer).css("background-color", COLORS[i]);
    .css('cursor', 'pointer');

    // expand section user clicks on and collapse other sections
    .click(function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log("here's id " + event.target.id);
        var div = "#div_" + event.target.id.slice(-1);
        console.log("here's div " + div);
    });
}
```

That code is in the `$(document).ready` function. It seemed to be working fine, then it got real slow, and I started trouble-shooting and realized the click was not always related to its associated `div`. The code is running [here](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/test/test) with some `log` statements. Here's an example of console output:

```
accordion.js:24 adding div element with id div_1   <--- so we can see the divs set up properly
accordion.js:24 adding div element with id div_2
accordion.js:24 adding div element with id div_3
accordion.js:24 adding div element with id div_4
accordion.js:35 here's id div_2
2accordion.js:35 here's id     <--- what?!?! seems to think it's being called from contents of div rather than from div
accordion.js:35 here's id div_4
accordion.js:35 here's id 
accordion.js:35 here's id div_2
accordion.js:35 here's id 
accordion.js:35 here's id div_2
```

**What am I missing? Why is the `click` event not binding to its associated `div` exclusively and how can I fix this?**

Comment: sounds like the event is propagating. Try stopping it. event.stopPropagation();

Comment: if that doesnt work try something like this if(event.target.nodeName === "div"){ // then do work here }

Comment: @TimCodes the stopPropagation did not work. It's not really propagating because when the click is called for the contents of the div it's not also called for the div. Seems to be an either or. I implemented your other suggestion, but this doesn't really help if I want users to be able to click anywhere in the div. It just means that if they click on the text rather than the div, nothing will happen, and they won't know why. Thanks for your help, and please let me know if you have any other suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `event.target` you'll get the actual element that was clicked on, even if it is a child of the element the click handler was attached to. To identify it's parent you should use `event.currentTarget`.

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

[Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

In your case `target` can be `h2` and `currentTarget` will always be the `div` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much obliged, esp. for the doc references.

Comment: Glad to help - and good to see a well described issue that's worth investigating. There's definitely many interesting details to discover in the documentation when it comes to event properties.